# Can I tell QGIS to load/show only a part of an image?

Tags: qgis, raster, image, loading, clip

can I tell QGIS to load/show only a part of an image without to extract this region as an extra/ new image?

Comment: Could you add an explanation why you would like to do that?

Comment: Use the [clipper](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_gdaltools.html) tool and output to a virtual raster (.vrt)